# Mongoose: Timestamps does not work with subdocuments

Tags: mongoose

I want to add timestamps to my subdocs but my `reponses` array does not contain any.

my model:

```js
const forumSchema = new Schema(
  {
    user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    content: { type: String, required: true },
    like: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }],
    reponses: [
      {
        user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
        content: { type: String, required: true },
        like: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }],
      },
//does not work
      {
        timestamps: true,
      },
    ],
    slug: { type: String, required: true },
  },
//this one works
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

And when I want to add a response I don't see any timestamps

```js
  Forum.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id }, { $push: data }, { new: true }, (err, question) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(404).send(err);
      } else {
        res.send(question);
      }
    });
```

I don't get any errors and my doc is updated as expected.

What am I missing please ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to define a saperate schema for responses and then use inside your main schema,

```
const responsesSchema = new Schema(
  {
    user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
    content: { type: String, required: true },
    like: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }]
  }, 
  {
    timestamps: true
  }
);
```

Use it in your schema,

```
const forumSchema = new Schema(
  {
    user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    content: { type: String, required: true },
    like: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }],
    reponses: {
      type: [responsesSchema]
    },
    slug: { type: String, required: true }
  },
  {
    timestamps: true
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks. There is no way to do it with nested documents ?

Comment: I have added a way in answer, What other way are you expecting?

Comment: I meant without separated schemas

Comment: I don't think it is possible, otherwise how mongoose understand the timestamp setting?

Comment: make sense. So I did follow your advice but instead of "reponses: {
      type: [responsesSchema]
    }," I did :  "reponses: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Answer" }]". No idea what is the difference (I'm not a mongoose expert) but it works. Thank you :)